# What are the differences between the Ruby 2.3 safe navigation operator '&. and the 'try!' method from ActiveSupport?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax

Are the safe operator `&.` from Ruby 2.3 and the `try!` method from ActiveSupport interchangeable? If they aren't, what are the differences between them?

Comment: http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/ has all you need to know.

Comment: TLDR: in most cases, they're virtually interchangeable, but there's a few subtleties you should be aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A key difference is that `try!` is a extra method call, whereas `&.` is not. I can think of one (admittedly contrived) difference this creates

```
"1234"&.gsub(/\d/, "a")
$& #=> "1234"
```

No surprises here - I did a regex match so the regex global variables are set (`$&` is the matched string).

But if (in a fresh irb session - this is important) I do

```
"1234".try!(:gsub, /\d+/, "a")
$& #=> nil
```

Then the regex related globals are nil. This is because these globals aren't really global - they are tied to where the code is called from (the docs call this thread and method-local global variables)

In this case `$&` is still getting set, but it is being set inside the `try!` method so you never see it.

The extra method call also makes `try` slower (pretty much an order of magnitude  in a quick benchmark) although in any real usage the cost of the actual method you are calling should dwarf the cost of `try!`