# Rails/Active Record- how to use 'take' if there is any matching record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a query that goes:

```
ModalType.where(id: modal['modal_id']).take.template
```

The problem is that i might run in cases where the query does not find any id: modal['modal_id'], then I get the error

```
undefined method `template' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I write something that would 'take' BUT only if where(id: modal_id) returns something (=is found) ?

Comment: Side note: this seems more declarative: `ModalType.find_by(id: modal['modal_id'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Ruby < 2.3:

```
object = ModalType.where(id: modal['modal_id']).take
if object
  object.template
else
  # I don't know. it's up to you
end
```

or

```
ModalType.where(id: modal['modal_id']).take.try(:template)
```

With Ruby >= 2.3 you can use safe navigation operator:

```
template = ModalType.where(id: modal['modal_id']).take&.template
```

Comment: thanks, i should have mentionned i was using ruby 2.3 :)

Comment: did not know of this "safe navigation", it's super useful

Comment: is this a new way of saying `.try(:template)`

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thanks @Ursus

Comment: My pleasure Sir

Comment: safe navigation and `try` have slight differences, it's better to be aware of them before interchangeably use them :) +1 btw)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko thanks , good advice => i checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34845254/what-are-the-differences-between-the-ruby-2-3-safe-navigation-operator-and-t

Comment: In the second snippet you can use a symbol: `take.try(:template)`